# Error in installing BIRT for FB Eclipse 4.5

Tags: eclipse, error-handling, flash-builder, birt

I am trying to install BIRT on my existing FLash Builder Eclipse 4.5

However, after all the preferences have been selected, when it actually begins to downlaod, I get this Error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flash.codemodel.core,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flash.codemodel.osgi,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flash.profiler,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flash.profiler.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.launching.multiplatform.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.launching.multiplatform.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.multiplatform.android.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.multiplatform.android.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.multiplatform.ios.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.multiplatform.ios.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.project.multiplatform.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flashbuilder.project.multiplatform.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.DCDService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.DCDService.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.ajaxbridge,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.ajaxbridge.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.as.editor,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.as.editor.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.axis2,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.axis2.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.codemodel,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.codemodel.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.crimson,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.crimson.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.css.editor,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.css.editor.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.dcrad,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.dcrad.derived,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.dcrad.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.e33,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.ui.actions,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.ui.e36,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.designview,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.designview.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.editorcore,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.editorcore.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.editors.derived,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.editors.derived.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.exportimport.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.core,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.core.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.standalone,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.standalone.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.flashbridge,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.flashbridge.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.flex,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.flexunit,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.flexunit.derived,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.flexunit.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.help,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.help.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.importartwork,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.importartwork.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.json,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.launching.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.launching.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.monitors.network,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.monitors.network.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.mxml.editor,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.mxml.editor.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.mxmlmodel,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.project,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.e35,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.BlazeDSService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.CFService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.CFService.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.HTTPService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.HTTPService.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.J2EEService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.J2EEService.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.LCDSService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.PHPService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.PHPService.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.StaticContentService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.StaticContentService.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.WEBService,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.WEBService.derived,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.services.WEBService.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.e36,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.tengine,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.tengine.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.ui,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.ui.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.utils.osnative,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexbuilder.utils.osnative.win,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.amt,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.as.core,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.as.core.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.communityhelp,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.communityhelp.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.css.core,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.css.core.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.designitems,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.editorcore,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.editorcore.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.editors.derived.e35,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.embeddedplayer,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.exportimport,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.exportimport.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.externaleditors,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.externaleditors.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.fcproject,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.fcproject.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.adobe.flexide.feature,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.adobe.flexide.feature.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.fonts,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.launching,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.launching.multiplatform,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.launching.multiplatform.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.launching.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.android,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.android.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.ios,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.ios.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.multisdk.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.mxml.core,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.mxml.core.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.playerview,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.project.multiplatform,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.project.multiplatform.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.refactoring.core,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.adobe.flexide.refactoring.core.nl1,4.5.0.308971
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.adobe.flexide.utils.feature,4.5.0.308971

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely has encountered is a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782).

The solution is to force Eclipse to download metadata from the update site again. This can be done by changing the url, such as adding a '/', or by removing and adding the update site again.